# Operator matrix is invertible if and only if its determinant is invertible

Tags: matrices, functional-analysis, operator-theory, c-star-algebras

Let $A,B,C,D$ are pairwise commutative operators on a Hilbert space $H$, then a necessary and sufficient condition that the operator matrix $$\begin{pmatrix} A&B\\C&D\end{pmatrix}$$ 
be invertible is that the formal determinant $AD-BC$ be invertible.

I do not have any idea for that. Please help me. Thanks.

Comment: $A,B,C,D$ are inevrtible?

Comment: @EmilioNovati : No, just operators on $H$ that commutes with each other.

Comment: Does the formula
$$
T := (AD-BC)^{-1}\begin{pmatrix} D & -B \\ -C & A\end{pmatrix}
$$
not work?

Comment: @PrahladVaidyanathan: Yes, if suppose $AD-BC$ is invertible, it works. what about other direction?

Answer (score 0):

**Note**: This answer is incomplete. I can't quite make it work, so I will leave it here in the hope that others can complete it :)

In addition the comment above, suppose
$$
S := \begin{pmatrix} A & B \\ C & D \end{pmatrix}
$$
is invertible in $\mathcal{B}(H\oplus H)$, then let $T$ denote its inverse and write
$$
T := \begin{pmatrix} U & V \\ X & Y \end{pmatrix}
$$
and note that
$$
I = ST = \begin{pmatrix} AU + BX & AV +BY \\ CU + DX & CV + DY \end{pmatrix}
$$
So
$$
AU+BX = I, AV+BY = 0, CU+DX = 0, \text{ and } CV+DY = I
$$
Hence,
$$
ADU+BDX = D, BCU+BDX = 0 \Rightarrow (AD-BC)U = D
$$
Also,
$$
ADV+BDY=0, BCV+BDY = B \Rightarrow (AD-BC)V = -B
$$
So,
$$
(AD-BC)(UY-VX) = DY+BX \qquad (\ast)
$$
However, 
$$
I = TS = \begin{pmatrix} UA+VC & UB+VD \\ XA+YC & XB+YD\end{pmatrix}
$$
and so
$$
XB+YD = I \qquad(\ast\ast)
$$
Perhaps if one can prove the necessary commutation relations, then $(\ast)$ and $(\ast\ast)$ will prove that $(AD-BC)$ is right invertible. Left invertibility should also be similar.

Comment: But $(DA-BC)U=D$. How do you say $(DA-BC)U=I$?

Comment: Sorry, my bad. Will try fixing it.